# How to make a textbox field required, in a Visual Studio Setup project?

Tags: c#, installation, setup-project

I have a custom dialog in my Visual Studio Seup project and need to know how to make the field required, so the user cannot progress (click next), if they don't enter a value into the textbox.

Comment: How did you create this dialog?  If it is just a Winforms one then use the Validating event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very rare to someone use Visual Studio Setup Project in order to make it's custom Setup ... normally we would use [WIX](https://wixtoolset.org/) or any other tool for builind the setup if the "normal" Visual Studio does not fit our needs.

[Scott Guthrie](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu) has a old post [about creating custom actions](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-creating-packaged-asp-net-setup-programs-with-vs-2005)... maybe it would be a good read for you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by configuring some [control events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368043%28VS.85%29.aspx) and creating a small message box custom action. You can find the generic approach here:
http://setupanddeployment.com/installation-user-interface/validate-user-input-installation/

Visual Studio setup projects do not support this directly, but you can edit your MSI with Orca. Another solution would be to use a setup authoring tool which allows you to modify control events.

Comment: http://setupanddeployment.com/installation-user-interface/validate-user-input-installation/ no longer valid. This is why solutions should be copied here, not linked to, unless linking to another SO article.